# How can i add long queue task at the end of function?

Tags: php, function

Actually i have add data function, which simple adding event. I want to send push notification to more than 3000 users, and these users data is also in the database. So for sending notification to them, i will have to retrieve all active users data, that's what i have done. Problem is that after adding event script is retrieving users and sending the push notification one by one in while loop and its taking so much time, and due to this function does not sending the success response `Event has been sent successfully`.

```
    Function AddEvent(){

    //Other Code.....

   // For sending notification to more than 3000 users
    $user = "SELECT ud.`ud_device_type`,ud.`ud_token` FROM `user` AS us LEFT JOIN `user_detail` AS ud ON us.`us_id`=ud.`us_id` WHERE  ud.`ud_notification` =1  and  us.`us_status`= 1  AND us.`is_enable`= 1 AND ud.`ud_device_type` = 'ios' OR  ud.`ud_device_type` = 'android' ";
            $selectSalt = mysqli_query($this->connection,$user);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($selectSalt) > 0){

                while($UserRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectSalt)){
                    $msg = 'There is New Event, tap to view.';
                    if($UserRow['ud_device_type']=='ios'){
                        $this->notify_ios($UserRow['ud_token'],$msg);
                    }
                    if($UserRow['ud_device_type']=='android'){
                        $this->notifyAndroid($UserRow['ud_token'],$msg);
                    }
                }
            }


   // Event add response for CMS
    $response['success'] = 'EvenRecord added successfully.';

      $output = array(
            'response' => $response,
        );

        echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


}
```

So can anyone guide me how can i adjust this kind of functionality that everything will work smoothly. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me. Thank You